# How do i download videos using praw? my code currently prints the url, but i want it to download the videos, instead of jsut printing it

Tags: reddit, praw

import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='id', client_secret='secret', user_agent='name')

for submission in reddit.subreddit("tiktokcringe").hot(limit=20):

```
if submission.is_video:
    print(submission.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Download [RedDownloader](https://pypi.org/project/RedDownloader/) by doing:

```
pip install RedDownloader
```

then you can do something like:

```
from RedDownloader import RedDownloader
RedDownloader.DownloadVideosBySubreddit("tiktokcringe" , 20)
```